# Как определить guid и id нужного меню в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Как определить guid и id нужного меню в Visual Studio, если соответствующей информации нет в документации (также в h и vsct файлах SDK) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос можно найти тут [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dr._ex/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1)
Однако это статья на английском, поэтому я быстро объясню этот процесс по-русски.
Итак надо в реестре Windows по указанному пути сделать изменение (если у вас другая версия Visual Studio, то 12.0 надо заменить, например на 10.0)

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\General] "EnableVSIPLogging"=dword:00000001`

то есть в папке HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\General присвоить EnableVSIPLogging значение 00000001. Хочу заметить, что у меня этого файла не было и его нужно было создать. Указанный код можно скопировать в файл с расширением .reg и запустить двойным щелчком (все выполнится автоматически). После этого перезапустите Visual Studio. Теперь, если вы зажмете Ctrl+Shift и попытаетесь вызвать какое-либо меню (например, сервис, файл, правка или просто кликните правой кнопкой рядом с кодом) то появиться сообщение в котором отобразится guid и id меню. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае я кликнул правой кнопкой в окне XAML разметки. Стоит отметить, что id меню является CmdID. Ну и наконец, чтобы было удобнее работать с этим, можно написать следующий код:

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidXamlEditor" value="{4C87B692-1202-46AA-B64C-EF01FAEC53DA}">
  <IDSymbol name="XamlEditorContextMenuID" value="259" />
</GuidSymbol>
```

после чего внедриться в это меню можно просто указав родителя (группе или меню)

```
<Parent guid="guidXamlEditor" id="XamlEditorContextMenuID"/>
```